# What does the parameter `index` mean in Apache POI sheet `getMergedRegion`?

Tags: java, apache-poi

What does `index` mean in `getMergedRegion`?

Apache's [HSSFSheet documentation](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#getMergedRegion%28int%29) does not explicitly describe what the `index` parameter means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the freely available source downloadable here http://poi.apache.org/download.html we have ...

```
/**
 * @return the merged region at the specified index
 */
public CellRangeAddress getMergedRegion(int index) {
    return _sheet.getMergedRegionAt(index);
}
```

When we drill down to `getMergedRegionAt` we find

```
public CellRangeAddress getMergedRegionAt(int index) {
    //safety checks
    MergedCellsTable mrt = getMergedRecords();
    if (index >=  mrt.getNumberOfMergedRegions()) {
        return null;
    }
    return mrt.get(index);
}
```

Here we can see that there is a `MergedCellsTable` this would indicate that each worksheet has a data structure that maintains a list of the Merged Cells in a WorkSheet.

From reviewing the code the index references the specific **MergedRegion** whose **CellRangeAddress** was required in the context of having many regions.

You could log that as a doc bug or submit a patch to improve the JavaDoc.

Answer (score 3):

To answer this question, let's first define a `MergedRegion`.

A `MergedRegion` is essentially a group of cells grouped together that can act as one cell. This is created using a [CellAdress](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellRangeAddress.html) which can span a number or rows or columns.

A `HSSFSheet` can contain a number of these `MergedRegions` given by [getNumMergedRegions](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getNumMergedRegions%28%29).

The index refers to the `MergedRegion` in the `HSSFSheet` in `Sheet` objects backing `MergedCellsTable` which is essentially an `ArrayList`.